# How to ASK if there is any country in the United Nations called “Paris” using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have been trying to do this query but im not sure about how is the syntax I need. I have seen a lot of examples of how to ask in a query to check if something is larger or shorter than other thing, but I have no idea of how to ask if something is IN other thing.

This is my last (failed) try:

```
PREFIX : <http:/dbpedia.org/resource/>
ASK
{
 FILTER(<http:/dbpedia.org/resource/Paris> IN <http:/dbpedia.org/resource/Member_states_of_the_United_Nations>)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the issue is that there's a DBpedia *resource* called

**http:/dbpedia.org/resource/Member_states_of_the_United_Nations**

but what you actually want, since its the value of the dct:subject property, is the *category*,

**http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Member_states_of_the_United_Nations**

For instance, you can get a list of countries that are member states with a query like:

```sql
select ?country {
  ?country a dbo:Country ; 
           dct:subject dbc:Member_states_of_the_United_Nations 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fcountry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20a%20dbo%3ACountry%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20dbc%3AMember_states_of_the_United_Nations%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

However, Paris isn't a country that's a member.  It's a city in France, which is a member.  You can *check* whether something is a member with an **ask** query like:

```sql
ask {
  dbr:France a dbo:Country ; 
             dct:subject dbc:Member_states_of_the_United_Nations 
}
```

[SPARQL results (true)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=ask%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3AFrance%20a%20dbo%3ACountry%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20dbc%3AMember_states_of_the_United_Nations%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You could get a list of populated places in countries that are member with a query like:

```sql
select ?city ?country {
  ?city a dbo:PopulatedPlace ;
        dbo:country ?country .
  ?country a dbo:Country ; 
           dct:subject dbc:Member_states_of_the_United_Nations .
}
```

[SPARQL results (limited to 100)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fcity%20%3Fcountry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20a%20dbo%3APopulatedPlace%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20a%20dbo%3ACountry%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20dbc%3AMember_states_of_the_United_Nations%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

and you can modify that to be an **ask** query that checks for cities with specific names.  E.g.:

```sql
ask {
  ?city rdfs:label "Paris"@en ;
        a dbo:PopulatedPlace ;
        dbo:country ?country .
  ?country a dbo:Country ; 
           dct:subject dbc:Member_states_of_the_United_Nations .
}
```

[SPARQL results (true)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=ask%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Paris%22%40en%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20a%20dbo%3ACountry%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dct%3Asubject%20dbc%3AMember_states_of_the_United_Nations%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 0):

Using the dc:hasPart term :

```
<http:/dbpedia.org/resource/Member_states_of_the_United_Nations> <http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-hasPart> <http:/dbpedia.org/resource/Paris>
```

This is described in [this w3 document](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/BestPractices/OEP/SimplePartWhole/).